# Using App.config in unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

We are developing a c# web application in which we are using some third party libs which are referencing different versions of Newtonsoft. 
In the web.config we have the same config section as in the example below. It works as expected.

But when we try to execute the unit test we get following error:

**System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

In our Visual Studio solution we have multiple projects for unit testing. I have created a app.config file (content below). This file is renamed and copied to the output folder during build.

Do I have to do this for every test project?

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Short answer would be **Yes**

Comment: This may be possible using an NUnit project file, although it's not commonly used functionality! Take a look at the thread here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/143

Comment: Particularly: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/143#issuecomment-266392548